# Undefined variable $snowsを解決したい

Tags: php, laravel

使ってるバージョン　laravel8
**問題**
Undefined variable $snows

**目標**
$snows関数を定義したい

**問題点**
laravelの初期ログイン画面のdashboard.blade.phpに自作のbaladeを貼り付けた。
dashboard.blade.phpに$snowsがルーティングされてないことは明白である。
そのため、snowsの行を'/dashboard'に変更するとnavigation.blade.phpにエラーが出る。
dashboard.phpに$dashborardと$snowsを成立させる必要がある。
web.phpにどう記載すればいいでしょか。

web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';

// 投稿一覧表を表示
// Route::get('/', 'SnowController@showList')->name('snows');
// Route::get('/list', 'SnowController@showList');
Route::get('/', 'SnowController@showDash')->name('snows');
// Route::get('/dashboard', function () {return view('dashboard');})->middleware(['auth'])->name('snows');

// 投稿画面表示
Route::get('/snow/create', 'SnowController@showCreate')->name('create');
// 投稿登録
Route::post('/snow/store', 'SnowController@store')->name('store');

// 投稿詳細を表示
Route::get('/snow/{id}', 'SnowController@showDetail')->name('show');

// 投稿編集を表示
Route::get('/snow/edit/{id}', 'SnowController@showEdit')->name('edit');
Route::post('/snow/update', 'SnowController@UpdateSnow')->name('update');

// 投稿削除
Route::post('/snow/delete/{id}', 'SnowController@exeDelete')->name('delete');
```

dashboard.blade.php（未定義部分）

```
 @foreach($snows as $snow)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $snow->id }}</td>
          <td><a href="/snow/{{ $snow->id }}">{{ $snow->title }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ $snow->created_at }}</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btnbtn-primary" onclick="location.href='/snow/edit/{{ $snow->id }}'">編集</button></td>
          <form method="POST" action="{{ route('delete', $snow->id) }}" onSubmit="return checkDelete()">
            @csrf
            <td><button type="submit" class="btnbtn-primary" onclick=>削除</button></td>
        </tr>
 @endforeach
```

コントローラー

```
//投稿一覧
    public function showDash() {
        $snows = $this->snow->findAllSnows();
        
        return view('dashboard',['snows' => $snows]);
    }
```

Comment: `findAllSnows()`とはなんですか？そもそも`snow`は何ですか？モデル？また「snowsの行を'/dashboard'に変更すると」というのはつまりどういうことですか？具体的な個所や差分で分かるようにしてください

Answer (score 0):

コントローラーの `view('dashboard',['snows' => $snows]);` より表示される場合 `$shows` が存在するので問題ないけど *web.php* の `view('dashboard');` からだと存在しないのでエラーになる、これを解消したい、てことで良いんですよね？

最終的に何をしたいのか解らないのですが、このパターンのエラーであれば

PHP: 新機能 - Manual / Null 合体演算子
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op
これを使えば未定義の値を特定の別の値に置き換えられるので、

修正前

```php
@foreach($snows as $snow)
```

修正後

```php
@foreach($snows ?? [] as $snow)
```

例えばこんなふうなやり方でエラーは解消できると思います。